# Accessing the parameters to functional paramters?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to do something like this, in Kotlin?

```
fun <P1, P2, R> curry2(fn: (p1: P1, p2: P2) -> R): (P1) -> R {
    return { p: P1 -> fn(p, p2) }
}
```

I'd like to get at the parameters of the functional parameter `fn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no special syntax for partial function application (providing some of the arguments), there are only [function references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) for *whole* signatures and lambdas to support the other use cases, including yours, if I get your idea right:

```
fun <P1, P2, R> curry2(fn: (P1, P2) -> R): (P1) -> ((P2) -> R) {
    return { p1: P1 -> { p2: P2 -> fn(p1, p2) } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey @hotkey : I see that I can also do this (sorry about the formatting):
```class CurriableFunction2<in P1, in P2, out R>(private val block: (P1, P2) -> R) {
    operator fun invoke(p1: P1, p2: P2) : R = block(p1, p2)
    fun curry(p2: P2): (P1) -> R = { p1: P1 -> block(p1, p2) }
}
```
Comments?

Comment: Probably you want to make `CurriableFunction2` implement the `(P1, P2) -> R` interface (this comes free, you'll just need to add `override` to `invoke`) so that it can be used where a function is expected. Apart from that, LGTM. Also, you could be interested in the currying implementation in https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale.